# generate some alert in view on getting the http post in some controller's action from an android client - Phalcon MVC framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, model-view-controller, phalcon

Hi I am working in an MVC framework.Recently, I have got some problem, here is the scenario:

I have an android client which sends an http post to url "**myweb/index/saveData**"(saveData is an action in the index controller)
I am getting the post from the android client and also able to insert in into my DB but the problem is I want to generate some notification based on inserted data on user's browser (user is signed in on my website!) also see the comment at the end of action. =>  saveData definition is:

```
public void saveDataAction(){
   //Getting POST FROM Android Client.
   $somedata1 = $this->request->getPost('data1');
   $somedata2 = $this->request->getPost('data2');
   //inserting data in DB.
   $data = new SomeData();
   $data->data1 = $somedata1;
   $data->data2 = $somedata2;
   $data->save();
   /*--> HERE AFTER INSERTION I WANT TO DO SOMETHING WHICH CAN SOMEHOW TELL 
         THE ONLINE USER ON THE WEBSITE THAT DATA IS INSERTED IN THE DATABASE 
         AND I CAN GENERATE SOME ALERT ON THE BASIS OF THIS DATA IN JS/JQUERY <--*/
}
```

Please tell me how can I acheive it.Also tell me if there is any other way or I can send the inserted data to jquery somehow and generate the notification through it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi. Do you want just to tell the user that was inserted in db?
Why you can't to do it right now?
If you call an alert() for example, it must work on both android or pc.

Comment: alert() is called from js and right now I'm in controller's action which is in PHP. just want to send something from here to client-side js so that I can generate notification from it.  thanks.

Comment: ok, but did you try echo "something" and check in js if the answer returns this "something" ?

Comment: echo will return the response to android client which is sending the http post to saveDataAction NOT to online user on web-browser.

Comment: So you could create a NotifyUser action in your controller, and use javascript setInterval method to request new notifications to logged user. Then, before returns the response of saveDataAction,  create a new notification of record added. After that, your request will get the record added notification and show it by a messagebox or something like that. Can you try it? If you have doubts, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Flashing Messages](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html)

Try this in end of your code..

For notifying success :

```
$this->flash->success("Great, We have updated user's status successfully.");
```

For notifying any error

```
$this->flash->error('Umh, We can\'t update user\'s status right now: \n');
```

after using flash message, don't forget to return this :

```
return $this->dispatcher->forward(array("controller" => "User", "action" => 'index'));
```